# Proof verification: Let $G$ be a group. Prove that $x^{a+b} =x^ax^b$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

My proof goes like this. Suppose that $x^{a+b} \neq x^ax^b$. Then $x^{-1+1} \neq x^{-1}x^{1}$, or $x^{-1}x^1 \neq e$, a contradiction of the definition of $x^{-1}$. Therefore $x^{a+b} = x^ax^b$.

Comment: There might be a counter example when $a=2,b=3$, for example

Comment: Double induction for proving it when $a,b \geq 0$, then $(x^{-1})^a = (x^a)^{-1}$ to conclude for $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 4):

Your proof is not true, you prove the result for $a=1, b=-1$, you have to prove it for every $a,b$.